# R: Minimizing Standard Deviation based by chanhing Weights Vector

Tags: r, matrix, optimization

Description of Problem:
The starting point is  the calculation of a standard deviation based on multiple Input Parameters. My Goal is to create an optimizer which changes a specific input variable to make the standard deviation = 0. In Excel I could simple use the GRG Nonlinear Solver:
**(Set Objective = standard deviation, Value Of=0, By Changing = Elements in the Input Vector, Subject to the Constrains= All Elements in Input variable >=** 0)

Is there an optimizer in R which can performs this Task, by considering all other interconnections of the Input Variable?